# С помощью getAttribute получить data-b атрибут с параграфов

Tags: javascript

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как решить следующее задание:
"Добавьте кнопку .b-19, которая запускает функцию f19. Функция с помощью getAttribute получает data-b атрибут с параграфов p-19 и выводит в out-19 через пробел. Обратите внимание, что элементов p-19 больше одного."
Свою попытку предоставляю ниже. Код выводит только содержимое последнего дата-атрибута.

```js
out19 = document.querySelector('.out-19');
p19 = document.querySelectorAll('.p-19');



for (let i = 0; i <= p19.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('.b-19').onclick = f19;
}

function f19() {

    data = p19[i].getAttribute('data-b');
    out19.innerHTML += data + ' ';
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Нужно вывести дата-атрибут каждого p друг за другом ,но выводится значение только последнего p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно?

```
out19 = document.querySelector('.out-19');
p19 = document.querySelectorAll('.p-19');
document.querySelector('.b-19').onclick = f19;


function f19() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= p19.length; i++) {
        let data = p19[i].getAttribute('data-b');
        out19.innerHTML += data + ' ';   
    }    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Оно самое!